# Vmware : Enable Drag and Drop files and folder between virtual machine and host

Tags: vmware

It was working to me , that i could drag a file / folder from Ubuntu virtual machine and drop it on windows 7 desktop , but for no know reason it stopped working .

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: VMware is a company, what software exactly are you using: Player, Workstation, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :

Reinstall **Vmware-Tools** and , that will uninstall the old installation .

Then restart your machine .

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have time to restart your guest or reinstall vmware-tools, you can try to start again the vmware-user-loader like example:

```
sudo  /usr/lib/vmware-tools/bin32/vmware-user-loader &
```

Comment: This is in the guest or on the host?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the virtual machine and it (drag & drop) worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging out different sides of the VM window. If you are lucky, one of them won't be active for anything else.

Window managers with features that activate on the edges (like docking windows, switching desktops, popping-out menus, etc.) seem to interfere with the VMWare Tools event that is supposed to notice you dragging files out. I have noticed this on several recent Linux desktop environments despite trying to turn off the edge features in the desktop settings. I wound up switching my window manager to Xfce to keep it simple and get the drag and drop reliably working.